# can access a specific position of an array but can't access specific object inside of this array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having an issue that as the title say for itself..

I can access a specific position of an array but can't access specific object inside of this array..

```
export const getAccessLevel = id =>{      

    const accessLevels = [
        {id: 0, name: 'Admin'},
        {id: 1, name: 'Customer'},
        {id: 2, name: 'Client'},
        {id: 3, name: 'Viewer'}
    ]

    let index = accessLevels.findIndex(array => array.id === id);
    console.log(index) // result : 3


    console.log(accessLevels[index]) 
    // this is returning {id: 3, name: "Viewer"}

    let AccessLevelName = accessLevels[index].name
    // this is return error : Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

    return AccessLevelName
}
```

Comment: Works for me when i do console.log(accessLevels[index].name)

Comment: I don't see a reason why this should not work. An alternative would be to use bracket notation for the field `accessLevels[index]['name']`, however, dot notation is normally preferred.

Both of the following tests worked without issues in my test using Babel:
`const array = [{foo: 1, bar: 2}, {foo: 2, bar: 3}]; console.log(array[0].foo); //prints 1 console.log(array[1]['bar']); //prints 3`

Comment: I suspect this may have to do with the specific argument of this function. Are you certain that when you get an error it's for the same call as when you get a successful `console.log` message? Are you sure there is not a result of `undefined` being logged before the error? Including in the question the specific call and log messages that result in an error would be helpful in diagnosing the issue.

Comment: I found the solution.. I answered my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem! It was happening because of react render order...
since the first time this function was called id was not defined..

which got the error right here :

```
let AccessLevelName = accessLevels[index].name
```

What I did to fix it was use useEffect hook.. when a action (redux) function  change data value that has id's value, it execute getAccessLevel one more time, but with id defined!

getAccessLevel :

```
export const getAccessLevel = id => {

    console.log(id)


    const accessLevels = [
        { id: 0, name: "Admin" },
        { id: 1, name: "Customer" },
        { id: 2, name: "Client" },
        { id: 3, name: "Viewer" }
    ];

    let accessLevel = accessLevels.find(array => array.id === id);
    console.log(accessLevel);

    let AccessLevelName = ''

    if (id) {
        AccessLevelName = accessLevel.name
    }

    return AccessLevelName;

}
```

UseEffect :

```
 useEffect(() => {
        props.findGroup(id)
    }, [])

    const handleAccessLevel = () =>{
        setAccessLevelName(getAccessLevel(props.data.accessLevel))
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        handleAccessLevel()
      }, [props.data])
```

Answer (score 4):

In this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-sky-szrw9) seems to be working, but I suggest you to use .find(), so you can have the object in just one call instead of getting it from an index. Just as

```
const getAccessLevel = id => {
    const accessLevels = [
      { id: 0, name: "Admin" },
      { id: 1, name: "Customer" },
      { id: 2, name: "Client" },
      { id: 3, name: "Viewer" }
    ];

    let accessLevel = accessLevels.find(array => array.id === id);
    console.log(accessLevel);

    let AccessLevelName = accessLevel.name;

    return AccessLevelName;
  };
```

Comment: This should not be the solution

Comment: I found the solution.. I answered my question